# What options exist for working with Windows Event Logs?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, snmp, event-log

What APIs and endpoints are available for working with Windows Event Logs?

What APS's are new/different in Windows Vista and newer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LogParser: Has a COM API as well as a command line application. Recommended. Also reads many other types of logs.

WMI: Can be made to read event logs. Doesn't perform well.

Windows API: If you are programming in C this is the way to go.

C#: Managed APIs exist also.

See the microsoft Windows Event Log API here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385785(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you know which option lets me use XML for queries, like eventvwr?

Answer (score 3):

There's [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhacse28(v=vs.90).aspx](http://bit.ly/K4rSLr)  Maybe you can provide some criteria (besides .net) to help people focus their answers?

Comment: Thanks Peter, Ben gave me a link that was the core low-level API that is not available in .NET.  That may be the fastest option.